# Award bounty to "answer" for unanswerable question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177585/restore-default-firefox-select-styling-with-inline-or-scoped-css) question about a css problem which *seems* as though it may not have a solution.  The problem is, I don't know for sure which is why I asked.

The one decent attempt at an answer postulates that what I'm asking is indeed not possible. How can I know if this is true or not?

Having offered a bounty for this question, am I obliged to award it to an answer that doesn't actually provide a solution to my problem?

Comment: You are never obliged to do that.  But won't the auto award give that answer half the bounty (it's the best with min score 2)?

Comment: I encountered a similar situation. I gave the bounty to the answer that seemed to me to be the best attempt. I have still not accepted an answer, and will not do so unless someone finds a way of doing what I want.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question?  it's tagged "discussion".. why the downvote?

Comment: @billynoah, voting on Meta is pretty sloppy. One or two stray votes either way mean very little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having offered a bounty for this question, am I obliged to award it to an answer that doesn't actually provide a solution to my problem?

The help page states:

> **If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount**. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

(emphasis mine.) So you are not obliged to award the bounty manually, but:

1. If you accept the answer, it will get the bounty.
2. Currently, there is an answer with a score of 2, so it will be awarded half the bounty automatically.

Comment: Number 2 is why I don't like the bounty system as it currently stands.

Comment: @RobH I don't like a lot of things on this site as they currently stand, I was just answering the question.